Python Logging not getting the desired caller class and line number
I have a python class wrapper to the logging functionality.
My problem with these solutions is the logging options "%(asctime)s:[%(filename)s->%(funcName)s():%(lineno)s] %(levelname)s>> %(message)s" will not refer to the original caller of the "write" method.
An example of what I am talking about, if I have class "Foo" in file foo.py:
class Foo:
    def bar():
        print("example")

Now at this point we want to introduce logging into the project without needing to change all files/classes of the project.
So creating a logger class and call it on file mainTest.py:
from foo import Foo
from logger import Logger

logger = Logger()
a = Foo()
a.bar()

The output will be:
2024-11-05 12:02:15,994:[logger.py->write():39] INFO>> example

While this is technically correct, I would like to know the class and function where the print occurred Foo.bar.
Here is the logger class on logger.py based from Here:
import logging
import sys
from datetime import datetime

class Logger(object):
    """
    Fake file-like stream object that redirects writes to a logger instance.
    """

    def __init__(self, log_level=logging.INFO):

        month = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m')
        self.logFile = f'./logs/{month}.log'

        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(self.logFile, "a")
        
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.handlers = []
        fh = logging.FileHandler(filename=self.logFile, mode = 'a')
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:[%(filename)s->%(funcName)s():%(lineno)s] %(levelname)s>> %(message)s')
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(fh)
        logger.setLevel("DEBUG")

        self.logger = logger
        self.log_level = log_level
        self.linebuf = ''

        sys.stdout = self

    def write(self, buf):

        self.terminal.write(buf)
        temp_linebuf = self.linebuf + buf
        self.linebuf = ''
        for line in temp_linebuf.splitlines(True):

            if line[-1] == '\n':
                self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip())
            else:
                self.linebuf += line
                

    def flush(self):
        if self.linebuf != '':
            self.logger.log(self.log_level, self.linebuf.rstrip())
        self.linebuf = ''

How could I make it so the output would be "2024-11-05 12:02:15,994:[foo.py->Foo.bar():4] INFO>> example"
How could I get the correct Function and Class name and line number?

Do you need to use print statements? The way it is usually done is by proper log statements (logger.info, logger.error, etc.) which are then processed by handlers

According to Python docs Logging HOWTO, print should be only used for console output (input prompts, etc)

Yes, I would prefer not to need to change every single class/file on the project. This method only needs 2 steps, 1) create a Logger Class and 2) instantiate it at the start of the "main" code.

You can use the stacklevel argument like this. (See the reference for detail.)
...
class Logger(object):
    ...
    def write(self, buf):
        ...
                self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip(), stacklevel=2)
        ...
    ...


self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip(), stacklevel=2)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/init.py", line 1374, in log
self._log(level, msg, args, **kwargs)
TypeError: _log() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stacklevel'

It's too old Python. Use Python 3.8 at least.

Thanks, that makes sense. I have already asked our Servers admins to upgrade it but they refuse to keep compatibility to older jobs..... anyway, they have confirmed in the future they will have some specific new machines with newer versions, but for now I need to wait. Thank you.

You can install a new Python environment such as Miniconda without affecting the existing Python environment. Or you can copy the system logging library source files(/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/*) into the project directory and modify it.
